# document.getelementbyId will return null if element is not defined?

Tags: javascript, domdocument

In my code, I see this:

```
if (document.getElementById('xx') !=null) {
    //do stuff
}
```

if `xx` element is not defined, will this evaluate to true or false?

Should I write:

```
if (document.getElementById('xx'))
```

to be safe?

Comment: ...`null if an element with the specified ID is not in the document` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById))

Comment: `document.getElementById('xx')` will returns `undefined`

Comment: @KhanhTran In fact it does return `null`. Test it in the console.

Comment: Bonus link: [DOM Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId). Yes, it's `null` there too.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
console.log(document.getElementById('xx') ) evaluates to null.

document.getElementById('xx') !=null evaluates to false
```

You should use `document.getElementById('xx') !== null` as it is a stronger equality check.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any scenario where it will return undefined?

Comment: Thank you for showing the console.log trick. You're teaching us to fish.

Comment: Just remember to remove the `console.log`s when you release!

Answer (score 29):

`getElementById` is defined by [DOM Level 1 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#method-getElementById) to return `null` in the case no element is matched.

`!==null` is the most explicit form of the check, and probably the best, but there is no non-`null` falsy value that `getElementById` can return - you can only get `null` or an always-truthy Element object. So there's no practical difference here between `!==null`, `!=null` or the looser `if (document.getElementById('xx'))`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since the only falsey value `getElementById` returns is `null`, there is no reason to check for any other value if you are only looking to check for existence.

Answer (score 10):

Yes it will return null if it's not present you can try this below in the demo. Both will return true. The first elements exists the second doesn't.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rBLVz/1/)

**Html**

```
<div id="xx"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
   if (document.getElementById('xx') !=null) 
     console.log('it exists!');

   if (document.getElementById('xxThisisNotAnElementOnThePage') ==null) 
     console.log('does not exist!');
```